# Git - serving two branches of the repo from apache

Tags: git, apache, git-branch

We have two branches of a git repo (team1 and team2). I want to serve the branches through apache under two hostnames or URLs. currently the main URL is serving team1. I want apache to serve team2 also so that they can check their updates in the server too. Please tell me how to configure this so that the updates to team2 should reflect in a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that has worked for me at least in single branch deployments:

*Following examples use a Linux environment.*

Create your bare Git repository on the server into a non-www-accessible location (e.g. `/home/someuser/repo.git`):

```
$ cd /home/someuser
$ mkdir repo.git
$ cd repo.git
$ git --bare init
```

Add the server's repo to your development repo's remotes:

```
$ git remote add production someuser@server:~/repo.git
```

Then create a `post-receive` hook (into `home/someuser/repo.git/hooks`) that checks the branch which was pushed:

```
#!/bin/bash
# post-receive

# Read hook input params.
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    # Get "simple" branch name from push data.
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)

    if [ "team1" == "$branch" ]; then

        # team1 branch pushed.

    elif [ "team2" == "$branch" ]; then

        # team2 branch pushed.

    fi
done
```

Then inside the if-else you need to get the pushed contents and deploy them to certain directories which have different virtual hosts assigned to them. Let's assume `team1` resides in `/var/www/team1/html` and `team2` resides in `/var/www/team2/html`.

The deployment happens with changing the server's repo's git work tree location and fetching the changes there. The following should make that happen for both teams:

```
#!/bin/bash
# post-receive

# Destinations to deploy repo contents to.
TEAM1_DEST="/var/www/team1/html"
TEAM2_DEST="/var/www/team2/html"

# Read hook input params.
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    # Get "simple" branch name from push data.
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)

    if [ "team1" == "$branch" ]; then

        # team1 branch pushed.
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$TEAM1_DEST git checkout -f team1

    elif [ "team2" == "$branch" ]; then

        # team2 branch pushed.
        GIT_WORK_TREE=$TEAM2_DEST git checkout -f team2

    fi
done
```

Remember to set `chmod +x` for the `post-receive` hook.

I've used this approach a few times for deploying websites on push. **NOTE**: the above hook has not been tested, but shows the principle.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create a new VirtualHost configuration in Apache. That defines the hostname that will determine where apache searches for the web-files.

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Sorry , this is not a question about creating virtual host.